# How to programmatically set JAX-WS 2.1 JMS client timeout in WebSphere 7?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, jax-ws

I'm converting a JAX-RPC client and service to JAX-WS, and am trying to figure out how to set the client timeout programmatically.  This will be a JAX-WS 2.1 client running in WebSphere 7.  In JAX-RPC, there was a property I could set on the SOAPBindingStub to set the timeout.

In the JAX-WS code, I've tried setting several properties as follows, with no luck:

```
PolicyFinderService policyFinderService = new PolicyFinderService();
PolicyFinder policyFinder = policyFinderService.getPolicyFinderSOAPPort();
((BindingProvider)policyFinder).getRequestContext().put(com.ibm.wsspi.websvcs.Constants.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY, 1);
((BindingProvider)policyFinder).getRequestContext().put(com.ibm.wsspi.websvcs.Constants.WRITE_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY, 1);
((BindingProvider)policyFinder).getRequestContext().put(com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.Constants.READ_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY, 1);
((BindingProvider)policyFinder).getRequestContext().put(com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.Constants.RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY, 1);
((BindingProvider)policyFinder).getRequestContext().put(com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.Constants.WRITE_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY, 1);
```

None of these have any effect when I make a call and the service isn't running, it just hangs for the default timeout value (I think 5 minutes) before timing out.

Has anyone found a way to programatically set this timeout value in WebSphere 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its possible you might need to

```
((BindingProvider)policyFinder).getRequestContext().put(
  com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.Constants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY, 2000);
```

it might do that before the write...possibly

perhaps this also?

```
reqCtx.put(JAXWSProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10); 
reqCtx.put(BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 10);
```

possibly REQUEST_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY may actually be in milliseconds, so maybe a low val of 1 gets rounded somehow to 0 (infinite) later on... maybe try 2000?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give those both a try.

Comment: It was the com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.Constants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY!  The current configuration is having trouble making the connection, so it never even gets to the other timeouts -- hence the connection timeout is needed.  Only thing is, it's in seconds, not milliseconds (I used a value of 10).  But still, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried all of the above properties but it didn't have any effect on the response timeout, i'm using a jax-ws client deployed on WAS v.7 to invoke a web service deployed on WebLogic v.10.3. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See article at http://www.websphere-world.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=2058.
Author, here details steps to set timeout for JAX-WS client in WebSphere. Regards, Mike